# VBA save .xls file in a specific location with a specific filename

Tags: excel, vba, save

I am trying to write a code that takes a .xls file and modifies the values in it after which saves it in a set location with a set filename that may always change based on the "NewSaveName" string but it gives me an error "Close' of object '_Workbook' failed" and I can't figure out why. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. The code I have written:

```
Workbooks("FormatSketch_DesignTable").Close SaveChanges:=True, Filename:="E:\FORMAT\Temp\" & SaveName & ".xls"
```

Could someone, please, help me solve this one?

Comment: Which version where the original file(s) created with?

Comment: It was created in Excel 2013

Comment: The issue is taht sometimes it DOES work and I'm wondering what could be the thing that breaks it. Maybe the fact that a user form is active during running it?

Comment: I don't think that would affect things. What happens if you separate the saving and closing in to 2 lines?

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error with `SaveName = ""` or with `SaveName = "a\"`. Does `SaveName` always contain the correct value?

Comment: I assume so, yes

Comment: It doesn't work either way, in one or 2 or 3 lines

Comment: There is exactly one unobvious point In the expression - variable `SaveName`. Try to make `fn = "E:\FORMAT\Temp\" & SaveName & ".xls"`, check the fullpath and then use `fn` in `.Close`

Comment: Oh, thanks! It worked, for now, :D I just need to call the string generation subroutine before this code. Thanks again!